# Dotnet Core with glade cannot find resource

Tags: c#, .net-core, gtk3, glade

I created the dotnet core project with gtk and glade.

Here is my project structure.

[image]

Program.cs

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Initialize Gtk.
            Application.Init();

            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();

            Application.Run();
        }
     }
```

MainWindow.cs

```
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {

      public MainWindow() : this(new Builder("MainWindow.glade")) { }

      public MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetObject("MainWindow").Handle)
      {
        builder.Autoconnect(this);
      }
    }
```

And, I already add resource file to csproj.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="MainWindow.glade" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="MainWindow.glade" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

I tried to call the mainwindow in Main() but I always get this error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentException: Cannot get resource file 'MainWindow.glade' (Parameter 'resource_name')
   at Gtk.Builder..ctor(Assembly assembly, String resource_name, String translation_domain)
   at Gtk.Builder..ctor(String resource_name)
   at helloOpenTK.MainWindow..ctor() in helloOpenTK/MainWindow.cs:line 12
   at helloOpenTK.Program.Main(String[] args) in helloOpenTK/Program.cs:line 21
```

Could you please suggest to me how to change the folder structure to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the solution after trying to create a new project with [gtkapp template](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GtkSharp.Template.CSharp/).

I changed the config in csproj and it can run with no error anymore.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="**\*.glade" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.glade">
      <LogicalName>%(Filename)%(Extension)</LogicalName>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
```